# Sending multiples emails with grails mail plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am trying to send an email and just after I send the first email. I want to send a second email to a different address. I am using Grails mail plugin.

To send the two emails I use:

**mailService.sendMail**{
*info first email*
}

**mailService.sendMail**{
*info second email*
}

In development the two emails are sending, but not in production.

Somebody have an idea?

Comment: Are you using the same mail server and same credentials in both environments?

Comment: Why is the "two" here relevant? How many mails are actually send in the production evironment? Have you checked the logs on your prod server? Have you tried ramping up the logging?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Yes i am using the same server with same credentials in both environments. The weird thing is when i send only one email at the time work fine.

Comment: @cfrick I said two because when I send only one everything works fine. The problem arrive when I sens more than one. I will check the logs like you said. Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to make that point more clear. Maybe also be clear about, whether the second call blocks or just does not send the email.  Also make sure to check the logs on the server you send the mails via (the SMTP server) whether there is something not working (e.g. "info second email" has just typo in it)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, i found the error. Was a bad path for an image.